# AngularJS controller constructors and compilers

Tags: angularjs

Is there a better way to handle the angularjs controller constructors that are compiler friendly?

My code keeps looking like this for each controller...

```
     return app.controller('WorkspaceCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$route', 'DashboardModel', 'dashboards', 'reports', 'workspaces', '$modal', 'growl',
           function WorkspaceCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $route, DashboardModel, dashboards, reports, workspaces, $modal, growl) {

            //.. controller code here ...
     }]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you are referring to the need to annotate dependencies for each controller to work after minification you can use [ng-min](https://github.com/btford/ngmin). It will handle the annotation of dependencies so that your code can be safely minified.

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo wow...thats exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Glad it helped. Posted as answer for future reference.

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo curious how this would work with requirejs since your paths are already defined and this is changing the output.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, however I am not experienced with requirejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ng-min](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) it will handle the annotation of dependencies so that your code can be safely minified. It is designed to be run as a [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) task as part of your build process.